# PayPal Donation button in form element

Tags: paypal, donations

I am having great trouble to make PayPal donation button works as when I want to add is in between form tag. So where PayPal button itself having own form tag and action but when inserting between my form tag it is taking my form action and completely ignoring PayPal own form action which is stopping to take donner to Paypal page.

Now limitation is I cannot move PayPal button nor my own Form tag or action so please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed a form within a form, which is why you're having the trouble you're having.

One thing you can do to fix the issue is to make your form post to a final confirmation page which would then post to PayPal.

If you want to avoid the final confirmation page you could make your form post to a processor script like PHP that generates the request to PayPal and sends the user over there accordingly.  The [Express Checkout API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec) is great for this sort of thing, but you would need to be familiar with web services in order to utilize that.

Comment: I got it what you mean. Thanks a lot